# Question on definition of finitely generated $K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The definition of a finitely generated $K$-algebra is if $R$ is generated as a ring by $K$ together with some finite set $r_{1},...,r_{n}$ of elements of $R$. I want to know what does that mean?

In fact I also want to know what does mean by generated as a ring by $K$?

Comment: I suppose $k=K$?

Comment: Yes it's K instead of k,sorry for typo!

Comment: The k-algebra has similar properties as the ring of polynomials with coefficients in k.

Answer (score 1):

This  simply means the elements of $R$ are polynomials in $r_1,,\dots, r_n$, i.e. the $K$-algebra homomorphism:
\begin{align}
K[X1, \dots,X_n]&\longrightarrow R\\X_1&\longmapsto r_1\\[-2ex] \vdots\;\\[-0.5ex]
X_n&\longmapsto r_n,
\end{align}
is surjective. We usually write this as $\;R=K[r_1,\dots, r_n]$.

Comment: I was also a bit confused by this common conclusion. How can I see that $R=K[r_1,...,r_n]$ just from the fact that there IS Some surjective ring homomorphism $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]\to R$? It seems this is often used as the definition. Also, I'm still curious about the answer to what it literally means for $R$ to be generated as a ring by K and $r_1,...,r_n$. Taking this literally, this means $R=<K,r_1,...,r_n>$, i.e. elements of $R$ are finite sums of the form $\sum a_ir_i$ with the $a_i\in <K, r_1,...,r_n>, r_i\in R$. Is this correct, and then how can we solely from this see $R=K[r_1,...,r_n]$?

Comment: Perhaps (informally): Can we just say that any element of $R$ can then be written as $f(p)$ for some $p\in K[X_1,...X_n]$, and any such element $p$ can of course be written as a finite sum $\sum a_ir_i$, where $a_i\in \{K, X_1,...,X_n\}, r_i\in K[X_1,...X_n]$. Thus by prop. of homom. $f(p)$ will be a finite $R$-linear combination of $\{f(x) : x\in \{K, X_1,...,X_n\} \}$, which will thus generate $R$. So, do we require $f$ to be the identity on $K$, and then we just say the generators of $R$ are $K$ together with $r_1=f(X_1), r_2=f(X_2),..., r_n=f(X_n)$?

Comment: @Christopher.L: Informally, yes, it corresponds more or less to your last comment. Namely, there is a finite number of elements $r_1,\dots, r_n\in R$ such that any element of $R$ is a finite sum of monomials $\; c_{k_1,\dots,k_n}r_1^{k_1}\dotsm r_n^{k_n}$ with coefficients in $K$. The homomorphism $\;f:K\longrightarrow R$ is defined as you say.

Answer (score 0):

R is k-algebra means there is a ring homomorphism f from k to R .R is finitely generated means there are x1,x2,..,xn in R
such that any element is polynomial of x1,x2,..xn with coefficients from f(k)i.e. range of f.
Any finitely generated k-algebra is isomorphic to quotient of k[x1,x2,..,xn] for some n.